# Why HTTP keep alive switched off by default in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

This is first time I'm implementing back-end in Node.js and I found that by default **HTTP Agent** has **keep alive** option switched off. For me it impacts a performance as I'm working with **AWS SDK** making tons of requests to its services. Actually my load testing helped to find that this option is switched off - so I enabled it and got much more better performance. I wonder if anybody knows why it's switched off by default? Is it **not to break a compatibility** (AFAIK this option was added few years ago) or for some other reason? Maybe I'm missing something? 
Found commit where it was added - https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/9fc9b87472806147b83c24d85b303c4f75d3021c

Nazar

Comment: Defaults usually try to cover the most  common use cases in the opinion of the developers. In this case the comment seems to indicate that it was found preferable to release resources rather than keep them in use as to prevent delays when trying to acquire new sockets (and possibly deadlocks if a script reaches the socket limit but won't let go of unused sockets)

Comment: @apokryfos thanks, got it. As far as I understand, proper socket timeouts should be set to avoid such deadlocks. Performance increase is significant when keep alive is enabled.